# How can I query by a list using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table `question_to_tag` with only two columns `tag_id` and `question_id`, the primary key constraint is `(tag_id, question_id)`.

Data stored looks like:

```
question_id1  | tag_id_2
question_id2  | tag_id_4
question_id3  | tag_id_2
question_id2  | tag_id_1
question_id1  | tag_id_1
question_id1  | tag_id_4
```

I want to get all the `question_id` with all `tag_id` in variable `tag_id_list` have `(question_id, tag_id)` in table.

How should I write the SQL?

Sorry all, I mistyped All to Any. Apologized for misleading you.

Comment: So tag_id_list is something like this? : tag_id_2,tag_id_3 ?

Comment: Just show `tag_id_list`

Comment: @Vivek.S You could assume it as (tag_id_1, tag_id_2).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you only need an IN clause :

```
SELECT question_id FROM question_to_tag WHERE tag_id IN (SELECT tag_id FROM tag_id_list)
```

Anyway the question is not really clear, so I had to guess the answer ...

Comment: his question was a bit vague, if the tag_list_id is not a variable but another table then you are ofcourse correct, we need to wait for an answer as to what he means by "variable"

Comment: @drakoumelitos even if it is a variable, if it is of type Table as I'm assuming the query will work .

Comment: my idea was that the variable is a list of ids :) like a string

Answer (score 0):

if you format your tag_id_list to be a comma separated value then you can do the following:

```
SELECT question_id FROM question_to_tag where tag_id in tag_id_list
```

Now it also depends what you mean by variable, is it in some other programming language? or is it a stored procedure and the variable is an SQL variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT question_id FROM table WHERE tag_id in (tag_id_list)
```